# How to give fixed length into chosen.jquery.js plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Have a day I used chosen.jquery.js plugin for my dropdownlist but it get width size automatically please somebody know how to choose a fixed length to my all dropdowlists.

Thanks.!

Comment: Are you asking about the width of your dropdown lists on the page?  Or asking about how many items are in the dropdown list?  I really don't understand the question.  Please show us your HTML or script that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem with you before. I solve this problem with set the width and max-width for the drop down.

```
<select class="chzn-select" name="chznName" >
...
</select>

<style>
    select, option {
        width: 500px;
        max-width: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

Chosen will create the chosen dropdown with width from the actual dropdown that you create.